# PS shows different RSS value from Pmap and Smem

Tags: linux, memory, ps, pmap

I want to get the memory consumption by a process. I am using *RSS* parameter to determine it.

I am getting same *RSS* value when I am using `pmap -xx <PID>` and with `smem` tool.
But when I am using `ps v <PID>` to get the RSS then it is showing different value.

I know for `pmap` and `smem` they use `/proc/pid/smaps` file to get *RSS* value but I don't have idea about `ps` tool.

What are the basis of this calculation in `ps` tool and which is correct `ps` or `pmap` and `smem`

Comment: The same question was asked 6 years earlier: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/56469/474546